# Scrape a table looping in specific dates using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been driving myself up the wall with trying to scrape the necessary historical coffee prices from the table found here using BeautifulSoup:
    http://www.investing.com/commodities/us-coffee-c-historical-data

I am trying to pull a market weeks worth of prices from 04-04-16 to 04-08-2016.

My ultimate goal is to scrape the entire table for those dates. Pulling all columns from Date to Change %.

My first step was to create a dictionary of the dates I want, using the date format of used in the element:

```
dates={1 : "Apr 04, 2016",
  2 : "Apr 05, 2016",
  3 : "Apr 06, 2016",
  4 : "Apr 07, 2016",
  5 : "Apr 08, 2016"}
dates
```

Next I want to scrape the table but I can't get it to do what I need to where it loops the dates in as needed so I have tried to pull the individual elements:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.investing.com/commodities/us-coffee-c-historical-data"
page  = requests.get(url).text
soup_coffee = BeautifulSoup(page)

coffee_table = soup_coffee.find("table", class_="genTbl closedTbl historicalTbl")
coffee_titles = coffee_table.find_all("th", class_="noWrap")

for coffee_title in coffee_titles:
  price = coffee_title.find("td", class_="greenfont")
  print(price)
```

except the value that is returned is:

```
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

Firstly, why am I returning a "None" value? I have a feeling it has to do with the coffee_titles part of my code, and it is not recognizing the column titles correctly.

Secondly, is there an efficient way for me to scrape the entire table using my date range in the dates dictionary?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code fails as you are looking for td tags in the headers  tags, if you print *coffee_titles*, it is pretty clear why  you  see `None`:

```
[<th class="first left noWrap">Date</th>, <th class="noWrap">Price</th>, <th class="noWrap">Open</th>, <th class="noWrap">High</th>, <th class="noWrap">Low</th>, <th class="noWrap">Vol.</th>, <th class="noWrap">Change %</th>]
```

There are no td tags.

To get all the table data, you can pull the dates from the table and use them as keys:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import OrderedDict

r = requests.get("http://www.investing.com/commodities/us-coffee-c-historical-data")
od = OrderedDict()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")

# select the table
table = soup.select_one("table.genTbl.closedTbl.historicalTbl")

# all col names
cols = [th.text for th in table.select("th")[1:]]
# get all rows bar the first i.e the headers
for row in table.select("tr + tr"):
    # get all the data including the date
    data = [td.text for td in row.select("td")]
    # use date as the key and store list of values
    od[data[0]] = dict(zip(cols,  data[1:]))


from  pprint import pprint as pp

pp(dict(od))
```

Output:

```
    {u'Jun 01, 2016': {u'Change %': u'0.29%',
                   u'High': u'123.10',
                   u'Low': u'120.85',
                   u'Open': u'121.50',
                   u'Price': u'121.90',
                   u'Vol.': u'18.55K'},
 u'Jun 02, 2016': {u'Change %': u'0.90%',
                   u'High': u'124.40',
                   u'Low': u'122.15',
                   u'Open': u'122.50',
                   u'Price': u'123.00',
                   u'Vol.': u'22.11K'},
 u'Jun 03, 2016': {u'Change %': u'3.33%',
                   u'High': u'127.40',
                   u'Low': u'122.50',
                   u'Open': u'122.60',
                   u'Price': u'127.10',
                   u'Vol.': u'28.47K'},
 u'Jun 06, 2016': {u'Change %': u'3.62%',
                   u'High': u'132.05',
                   u'Low': u'127.10',
                   u'Open': u'127.30',
                   u'Price': u'131.70',
                   u'Vol.': u'30.65K'},
 u'May 09, 2016': {u'Change %': u'2.49%',
                   u'High': u'126.60',
                   u'Low': u'123.28',
                   u'Open': u'125.65',
                   u'Price': u'126.53',
                   u'Vol.': u'-'},
 u'May 10, 2016': {u'Change %': u'0.29%',
                   u'High': u'125.90',
                   u'Low': u'125.90',
                   u'Open': u'125.90',
                   u'Price': u'126.90',
                   u'Vol.': u'0.01K'},
 u'May 11, 2016': {u'Change %': u'2.26%',
                   u'High': u'129.77',
                   u'Low': u'126.88',
                   u'Open': u'128.60',
                   u'Price': u'129.77',
                   u'Vol.': u'-'},
 u'May 12, 2016': {u'Change %': u'-1.21%',
                   u'High': u'128.75',
                   u'Low': u'127.30',
                   u'Open': u'128.75',
                   u'Price': u'128.20',
                   u'Vol.': u'0.01K'},
 u'May 13, 2016': {u'Change %': u'0.47%',
                   u'High': u'127.85',
                   u'Low': u'127.80',
                   u'Open': u'127.85',
                   u'Price': u'128.80',
                   u'Vol.': u'0.01K'},
 u'May 16, 2016': {u'Change %': u'3.03%',
                   u'High': u'131.95',
                   u'Low': u'128.75',
                   u'Open': u'128.75',
                   u'Price': u'132.70',
                   u'Vol.': u'0.01K'},
 u'May 17, 2016': {u'Change %': u'-0.64%',
                   u'High': u'132.60',
                   u'Low': u'132.60',
                   u'Open': u'132.60',
                   u'Price': u'131.85',
                   u'Vol.': u'-'},
 u'May 18, 2016': {u'Change %': u'-1.93%',
                   u'High': u'129.65',
                   u'Low': u'128.15',
                   u'Open': u'128.85',
                   u'Price': u'129.30',
                   u'Vol.': u'0.02K'},
 u'May 19, 2016': {u'Change %': u'-4.14%',
                   u'High': u'129.00',
                   u'Low': u'123.70',
                   u'Open': u'128.95',
                   u'Price': u'123.95',
                   u'Vol.': u'29.69K'},
 u'May 20, 2016': {u'Change %': u'0.61%',
                   u'High': u'125.95',
                   u'Low': u'124.25',
                   u'Open': u'124.75',
                   u'Price': u'124.70',
                   u'Vol.': u'15.54K'},
 u'May 23, 2016': {u'Change %': u'-2.04%',
                   u'High': u'124.70',
                   u'Low': u'122.00',
                   u'Open': u'124.50',
                   u'Price': u'122.15',
                   u'Vol.': u'15.89K'},
 u'May 24, 2016': {u'Change %': u'-0.29%',
                   u'High': u'123.30',
                   u'Low': u'121.55',
                   u'Open': u'122.45',
                   u'Price': u'121.80',
                   u'Vol.': u'15.06K'},
 u'May 25, 2016': {u'Change %': u'-0.33%',
                   u'High': u'122.95',
                   u'Low': u'121.20',
                   u'Open': u'122.45',
                   u'Price': u'121.40',
                   u'Vol.': u'18.11K'},
 u'May 26, 2016': {u'Change %': u'0.08%',
                   u'High': u'122.15',
                   u'Low': u'121.20',
                   u'Open': u'121.90',
                   u'Price': u'121.50',
                   u'Vol.': u'19.27K'},
 u'May 27, 2016': {u'Change %': u'-0.16%',
                   u'High': u'122.35',
                   u'Low': u'120.80',
                   u'Open': u'122.10',
                   u'Price': u'121.30',
                   u'Vol.': u'13.52K'},
 u'May 31, 2016': {u'Change %': u'0.21%',
                   u'High': u'123.90',
                   u'Low': u'121.35',
                   u'Open': u'121.55',
                   u'Price': u'121.55',
                   u'Vol.': u'23.62K'}}
```

Now to get specific dates, we need to mimic and ajax call with a post to `http://www.investing.com/instruments/HistoricalDataAjax`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import OrderedDict

# data to post
data = {"action": "historical_data",
        "curr_id": "8832",
        "st_date": "04/04/2016",
        "end_date": "04/08/2016",
        "interval_sec": "Daily"}

# add a user agent and specify that we are making an ajax request
head = {

        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.post("http://www.investing.com/instruments/HistoricalDataAjax", data=data, headers=head)
    od = OrderedDict()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

    table = soup.select_one("table.genTbl.closedTbl.historicalTbl")
       cols = [th.text for th in table.select("th")][1:]
    for row in table.select("tr + tr"):
        data = [td.text for td in row.select("td")]
        od[data[0]] = dict(zip(cols, data[1:]))

from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(dict(od))
```

Now we only get the date range from *st_date* to *end_date*:

```
{u'Apr 04, 2016': {u'Change %': u'-3.50%',
                   u'High': u'126.55',
                   u'Low': u'122.30',
                   u'Open': u'125.80',
                   u'Price': u'122.80',
                   u'Vol.': u'25.18K'},
 u'Apr 05, 2016': {u'Change %': u'-1.55%',
                   u'High': u'122.85',
                   u'Low': u'120.55',
                   u'Open': u'122.85',
                   u'Price': u'120.90',
                   u'Vol.': u'25.77K'},
 u'Apr 06, 2016': {u'Change %': u'0.50%',
                   u'High': u'122.15',
                   u'Low': u'120.00',
                   u'Open': u'121.45',
                   u'Price': u'121.50',
                   u'Vol.': u'17.94K'},
 u'Apr 07, 2016': {u'Change %': u'-1.40%',
                   u'High': u'122.60',
                   u'Low': u'119.60',
                   u'Open': u'122.35',
                   u'Price': u'119.80',
                   u'Vol.': u'32.69K'}}
```

You can see the post requests in chrome developer tools under the *xhr* tab:

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic thank you @padraiccunningham for your input and thanks for highlighting the issue I was having with not pinpointing the correct header tags, I believe that could be construed as a beginner oversight! Thanks for taking some time to help out with my question. If you could, can you please explain the step to mimic and ajax call post to [link](http://www.investing.com/instruments/HistoricalDataAjax)? I don't quite understand what is going on there or why this is necessary in order to call specific dates?

Comment: The only issue I have just noticed are that the header columns seem to have come in staggered. Where u 'Date' is that should be u 'Price' and so forth. The heading u 'Change %' has not come in as the Date column has pushed it down. I hope that makes sense, technically u 'Date' does not have to come in

Comment: @da4l, We should not have been including the Date in cols as that is our main key in the dict. For the ajax requests that is how the data is retrieved in your browser, open developer tools and look at what happens when you change some dates, it is not a simple get requests with the start and end date as params.